# Simple HTML file field uploads for an Assets field that appears in a Matrix field in a Safecraker form

Tags: matrix, assets, safecracker

I have a Safecracker form that contains a Matrix field, that contains an Assets field.

Is there anyway to handcraft the matrix field as per this article:

- http://themetaq.com/articles/bring-matrix-data-editing-to-the-front-end

Whilst using an Asset field?

I've found this SE question that relates to using a simple HTML file field in for Assets:

- [Simple HTML file field uploads with Assets and Safecracker](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/simple-html-file-field-uploads-with-assets-and-safecracker)

However I cannot get this to work when it sit's inside a Matrix field. I'm using the code below; **assets_file** is the name of the Matrix field, and the 2nd Matrix Column is a textfield which saves to the database on submission OK.

```
{exp:safecracker channel="asset" return="/assets/upload/success"}

  {!-- Row Order Value --}
  <input type="hidden" name="asset_files[row_order][]" value="row_new_0">

  {!-- 1st Column Asset Field --}
  <input type="file" name="asset_files[row_new_0][col_id_1]" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="asset_files[row_new_0][col_id_1]_filedir" value="2">

  {!-- 2nd Column Text Field --}
  <input type="text" name="asset_files[row_new_0][col_id_2]" value="">

  {!-- Title & URL Title fields removed for simplicity --}

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

{/exp:safecracker}
```

I've tried using the name of **asset_files_filedir** for the hidden field of the 1st Column Asset Field, but it doesn't make a difference.

To clarify the form submits successfully - creates the entry and even adds the 2nd Column Text Field to the matrix field. It is only the file that doesn't get uploaded.

I suppose I asking if this is possible, and if so does anyone know how would I do this?

- EE: 2.5.5
- Safecracker: 2.1
- Matrix: 2.5.5
- Assets: 2.1.4

Thanks